# 'Forces' enacted by hot neutrons in fusion bomb - Pauli exclusion

Tags: electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, fusion, neutrons, strong-force

Are Pauli exclusion 'forces' on a neutron 100% electromagnetic (Lennard-Jones seems more acute relationship compared to electrostatic force)
If so does that neutrons have two forces between them - 'electrodynamic' repulsion and the strong meson attraction? 
Thus, in nuclear fusion bombs, I read the neutrons initiate fusion on Lithium deuteride by collision. Is this by Pauli/ED forces, mesons/strong force or both?

Comment: The neutron can cause the Li6(n,T)$\alpha$ reaction, making tritium that could then fuse with deuterium.

Comment: Is the usefulness of neutrons in fusion in a very specific reaction/ one-trick pony? I wondered why they don't use lasers to create 'hot' neutrons to bombard fusion fuel? I see some Japanese scientists are accelerating electrons with lasers. Is it easier/more efficient to accelerate an electron than a neutron with a laser and are electrons more likely to raise the temperature?